# How to fix error: JSON.parse: unexpected character?

Tags: javascript

I get this error when Im running the code bellow: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
data = JSON.parse(data);

When I run console.log(data); Its says that data is undefined.

```
console.log(data);
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Does somebody know how to fix the error problem?

Comment: Why don't you show us the problematic code (the string to parse)? Most likely you have whites paces or control characters in your JSON string.

Comment: We need to see how you are initialising data.

Comment: Pls provide more information?

Comment: @xbonez var data = window.localStorage.getItem(key);

Comment: what is output of window.localStorage.getItem(key);

Comment: @adamjc 
var key = $(this).attr("track_id");

$("#track_info div[data-role=header] h1").text(key);
var data = window.localStorage.getItem(key);

console.log(data);

data = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: @ckv Thanks, but what more information do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the JSON.parse() method syntax is `JavaScriptObject JSON.parse(String)`.
It means the JSON.parse() method takes a valid JSON string as argument and it returns a JavascriptObject. If the String, which is passed as the argument is not a valid JSON String then it will throw an error.
So,first you have to pass a valid JSON String as argument to the `JSON.parse()`method.

Comment: Thanks, but what is a valid JSON String as argument? Can you show me in the right direction...

Comment: valid JSON string is nothing but which is synatactically correct JSON. Generally the JSON data consists of "{}"---->for JSONObject and "[]"------->for JSONArray.

Comment: Inside a JSON Object the elements should be like...              key:value pairs,   for eg: {"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}                                       inside a JSON arry the elements should be..............             only values.......                  for eg:              [val1,val2,val3]

Answer (score 0):

Data is undefined. Thats why JSON.parse throws an error. So investigate what is the value for 'data'.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok for you to treat empty/undefined data as empty json object then try this:

```
var key = $(this).attr("track_id"); 
$("#track_info div[data-role=header] h1").text(key); 
var data = window.localStorage.getItem(key); 

if (data == undefined || data == null || data == "")
{
    data = 'null';
}
else
{
    console.log(data);
}

data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data);
```

Using `data = 'null';` I have created null json object so that `JSON.parse()` doesn't fail.

Comment: JSON.parse() will still fail if the data is incorrectly formatted or not even JSON.

Comment: @Adrian yes, you are correct. If OP adds more info, I'll try to update the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
var key = $(this).attr("track_id");
$("#track_info div[data-role=header] h1").text(key);

var data = window.localStorage.getItem(key);

console.log(data); /* The output here may indicate the problem */
                   /* valid JSON should be a string like 
                          "{ \"propName\":\"propValue\" , ...}"
                   */

try{
    data = JSON.parse(data);
}
catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

But without knowing more about your code it's very difficult to help...are you using jQuery? ( $(...) can be used by other libraries too.)

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON for more examples of JSON, plus a good overview.
Also http://www.json.org/

Comment: Thanks, but when I use your code I get this error: TypeError: data[i].coords is undefined + total_km += gps_distance(data[i].coords.latitude, data[i].coords.longitude, data[i+1].coords.latitude, data[i+1].coords.longitude);. data is still undefined...

Comment: That doesn't look like it came from 'my' code. Put a breakpoint on the console.log(data) line and examine the data variable in debugger.

Comment: As many people have said to you, it's very difficult to help you because you are not explaining what you are trying to do, or showing enough code and details for us to provide help.

Comment: because there is no data stored in the client's localStorage with whatever key you have in the attribute "track_id" or whatever element 'this' refers to. You need to provide it or gracefully handle the missing data.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can not fix my error problem... I dont know what to do...